# Как сделать в Unity слайдер, который будет отвечать за скорость передвижения объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть поезд, которые двигается по горизонтали. Имеется слайдер, который должен отвечать за скорость передвижения поезда. **Как прописать данный код?** Вот код который у меня уже есть:

```
public bool flag = false;
float speed = 0.2f;
public GameObject cub;
public Text text;
public Light l;

public void button(){
    if (flag)
        flag = false;
    else
        flag = true;
}

void Update() {
    if (flag) {
        transform.Translate (new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0));
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    Debug.Log ("Сработал триггер и остановился поезд");
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube") {
        flag = false; // остановится
    }

}
```

Картинка для наглядности.
[image: Поезд Unity]

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае не совсем понятно, слайдер будет сам отвечать за скорость (то есть его значение и есть `speed`) или слайдер будет влиять на скорость `speed`.

Предположим, что у нас изначально управление идет кнопками влево/вправо. Движение будет такое:

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
}
```

Чтобы воспользоваться значением слайдера нужно это значение оттуда взять. Это можно сделать тысячей способов и всё зависит от ситуации и сложности игры и пр.

1. Способ — сделать публичную переменную в скрипте

   ```
   public Slider slider;
   ```

   Она  потребует импорта пространства имен `using UnityEngine.UI;`

   И далее в эту переменную в инспекторе перенести сам слайдер из канваса
2. Способ — тоже сделать переменную в скрипте, но при этом найти слайдер при старте программы

   ```
   void Start () {
       slider = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Slider").gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>();
   }
   ```

   Как работать с `Find` можно посмотреть **[в документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)**.
3. Способ — еще куча вариантов...

В итоге в переменной `slider` будет ссылка на объект. Теперь просто **[смотрим на его параметры](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html)** и банально применяем его переменную **[value](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-value.html)**.

```
void Update () {     
    // var x = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * slider.value * Time.deltaTime;
    var x = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * slider.value * Time.deltaTime;  
    transform.Translate(x, 0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать в классе, код которого Вы предоставили, функцию, `public void OnSliderValueChanged(float newValue)`, и кинуть ссылку на этот метод на сам Slider. (название функции можно придумать любое, но сигнатура должна быть именно такой. т.е. `public void название(float параметр){}`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(скриншот взят с офф сайта документации Unity (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Slider.html). нет возможности запустить у себя)

Slider, при изменении значения, сам передаст новое значение в написанную функцию. А уже в ней пишите свою логику обработки этого значения (то как оно будет влиять на скорость).